# Getting error while connecting JMX with jconsole

Tags: jboss, jvm, jmx, jconsole, pega

I am having jboss server configured, trying to remotely moniotor JVM.I have configured JMX in standalone file. But while I am trying to connect from jconsole I am getting error as connecion time out.We are using JBOSS on top of it pega aaplication

Version:

JBOSS - 7.1
JDK - 1.8.231

The configuration I have set it up is

```
if [ "x$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS" = "x" ]; then
   JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS="org.jboss.byteman,org.jboss.logmanager"
fi

-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS 
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9000 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.162.2.80"
```

Jar and file path

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/rh/jboss-eap-7.1/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-2.0.7.Final-redhat-1.jar -Xbootclasspath/p:/opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/wildfly-common-1.5.2.Final.jar"

-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
```

When I am trying to coonect to server I am getting this as tcpdump value.

```
16:10:33.179092 IP 10.19.11.226.53154 > appealdevop2.moj.cslistener: Flags [S], seq 4263944898, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:10:36.179364 IP 10.19.11.226.53154 > appealdevop2.moj.cslistener: Flags [S], seq 4263944898, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
16:10:42.179703 IP 10.19.11.226.53154 > appealdevop2.moj.cslistener: Flags [S], seq 4263944898, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

I have tried all the settings but not able to find the result.

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to include the JBoss client libraries to your JMX tool. 
(i.e. you have to add *JBOSS_HOME/bin/client/jboss-cli-client.jar* to the classpath of the JMX tool.)

For JConsole you can use directly the script :

```
    JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh
```

You have to use the defined address binding of management interface (see section <interface name="management"> in standalone.xml and related port (see <socket-binding> default is 9990). So your remote connection string will look something like this:

```
 service:jmx:remote+http://[your-server-ip]:9990
```

Comment: I have extended my answer maybe this helps